# Controlling the unpacking of multiple variadic parameter packs for a fancier tuple_for_each

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

## Background/Motivation

I've been playing around with VC++2015, looking at some ways of writing utility routines to handle tuples and other variadic bits and pieces.

My first function of interest is the common-or-garden tuple_for_all function. For a function `f` and a tuple `t` call in turn `f(get<0>(t)`, `f(get<1>(t)`, and so on.

So far, so straightforward.

```
template<typename Tuple, typename Function, std::size_t... Indices>
constexpr void tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    using swallow = int[];
    static_cast<void>(swallow{ 0, (std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))), void(), 0)... });
}

template<typename Function, typename Tuple>
constexpr void tuple_for_each(Function&& f, Tuple&& t) {
    return tuple_for_each_aux(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>{});
}
```

OK, that works (modulo any compilation and copy/paste errors that occurred in cutting this down).

But my next thought was that the `Function` might return a useful/interesting value in some cases, and so we should capture it. Naively, we could do something like this:

```
template<typename Tuple, typename Function, std::size_t... Indices>
constexpr auto tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)));
}

template<typename Function, typename Tuple>
constexpr auto tuple_for_each(Function&& f, Tuple&& t) {
    return tuple_for_each_aux(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>{});
}
```

That's great for when the functions do return a value, but since `void` is annoyingly degenerate and we can't make a `std::tuple<void>`, it won't work for `void`-returning functions. We can't directly overload by return type, but C++ gives us the tools handle this, with SFINAE:

```
template<typename Function, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Indices, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Function(std::tuple_element_t<0, std::decay_t<Tuple>>)>>::value>>
constexpr void tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    using swallow = int[];
    static_cast<void>(swallow{ 0, (std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))), void(), 0)... });
}

template<typename Function, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Indices, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Function(std::tuple_element_t<0, std::decay_t<Tuple>>)>>::value>>
constexpr decltype(auto) tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)))...);
}

template<typename Function, typename Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) tuple_for_each(Function&& f, Tuple&& t) {
    return tuple_for_each_aux(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>{});
}
```

This is nice enough. It'd be nice if the evaluation order were consistent between the two (the `void` version is left-to-right, the value-returning version is up to the compiler, so probably right-to-left). We can fix that by eschewing the call to `std::make_tuple` and instead brace initializing a `std::tuple` instead. I don't know if there's something better than the `decltype(std::make_tuple(...))` to get the right type to construct. There may be.

```
template<typename Function, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Indices, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Function(std::tuple_element_t<0, std::decay_t<Tuple>>)>>::value>>
constexpr void tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    using swallow = int[];
    static_cast<void>(swallow{ 0, (std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))), void(), 0)... });
}

template<typename Function, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Indices, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Function(std::tuple_element_t<0, std::decay_t<Tuple>>)>>::value>>
constexpr decltype(auto) tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    return decltype(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)))...)){std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))) ...};
}

template<typename Tuple, typename Function>
constexpr decltype(auto) tuple_for_each(Function&& f, Tuple&& t)
{
    return tuple_for_each_aux(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>{});
}
```

(Incidentally, VC++ 2015 appears to be bugged right now; it [still doesn't use left-to-right evaluation](http://www.twitter.com/joncaves/status/628053473012002816) even for the braced initializer because the optimizer team [doesn't seem to think it's important](http://www.twitter.com/joncaves/status/628055820106752000))

I'm more interested in the `std::enable_if_t` check. We do not examine to see if the function returns non-`void` for every type in the tuple, only the first. But really, it should be all-or-nothing. [Columbo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253399/check-traits-for-all-variadic-template-arguments/28253503#28253503) `all_true` technique takes care of that for us:

```
template <bool...> struct bool_pack;

template <bool... v>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, v...>, bool_pack<v..., true>>;

template<typename Function, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Indices, typename = std::enable_if_t<all_true<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Function(std::tuple_element_t<Indices, std::decay_t<Tuple>>)>>::value...>::value>>
constexpr void tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    using swallow = int[];
    static_cast<void>(swallow{ 0, (std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))), void(), 0)... });
}

template<typename Function, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Indices, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Function(std::tuple_element_t<0, std::decay_t<Tuple>>)>>::value>>
constexpr decltype(auto) tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    return decltype(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)))...)){std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))) ...};
}

template<typename Function, typename Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) tuple_for_each(Function&& f, Tuple&& t)
{
    return tuple_for_each_aux(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>{});
}
```

## Problem

But here's the bit that's tricky. While `tuple_for_each` is nice and useful, I thought, what if I spiced it up a little? How about `tuple_for_each` that takes a function `f` and tuples `t0`, `t1`, etc. and computes `f(get<0>(t0), get<0>(t1)...)`, `f(get<1>(t0), get<1>(t1)...)` and so on?

Naively we'd like to do something like this:

```
    using swallow = int[];
    static_cast<void>(swallow{ 0, ((std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuples>(ts))...)), void(), 0)... });
```

Naively, we'd like the first `...` to expand `Tuples`, and the second `...` to expand `Indices`. But parameter pack expansions don't offer this kind of control. If the expression before the `...` contains multiple parameter packs, then the `...` tries to unpack all of them in parallel (VC++; it emits a compiler error that they are different lengths), or cannot find the parameter packs at all (g++; it emits a compiler error that there are no packs).

Fortunately, this case can be handled with an additional layer of indirection to separate out the expansions:

```
template <bool...> struct bool_pack;

template <bool... v>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, v...>, bool_pack<v..., true>>;

template<size_t N, typename Function, typename... Tuples, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Function(std::tuple_element_t<N, std::decay_t<Tuples>>...)>>::value>>
constexpr void tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuples&&... ts)
{
    return std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<N>(std::forward<Tuples>(ts))...);
}

template<typename Function, typename... Tuples, std::size_t... Indices, typename = std::enable_if_t<all_true<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Function(std::tuple_element_t<0, std::decay_t<Tuples>>...)>>::value>::value>>
constexpr void tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>, Tuples&&... ts)
{
    using swallow = int[];
    static_cast<void>(swallow{ 0, (tuple_for_each_aux<Indices>(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Tuples>(ts)...), void(), 0)... });
}

template<std::size_t N, typename Function, typename... Tuples, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Function(std::tuple_element_t<N, std::decay_t<Tuples>>...)>>::value>>
constexpr decltype(auto) tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuples&&... ts)
{
    return std::forward<Function>(f)(std::get<N>(std::forward<Tuples>(ts))...);
}

template<typename Function, typename... Tuples, std::size_t... Indices, typename = std::enable_if_t<all_true<!std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Function(std::tuple_element_t<0, std::decay_t<Tuples>>...)>>::value>::value>>
constexpr decltype(auto) tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>, Tuples&&... ts)
{
    return decltype(std::make_tuple(tuple_for_each_aux<Indices>(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Tuples>(ts)...)...)) { tuple_for_each_aux<Indices>(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Tuples>(ts)...)... };
}

template<typename Function, typename Tuple, typename... Tuples>
constexpr decltype(auto) tuple_for_each(Function&& f, Tuple&& t, Tuples&&... ts)
{
    return tuple_for_each_aux(std::forward<Function>(f), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>{}, std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::forward<Tuples>(ts)...);
}
```

That works fine... except... those pesky enable_ifs. I had to weaken them, back to testing only the first elements in the tuples. Now, it's not a complete disaster, because the inner-most expansion can perform the check. But it's not great. Consider the following:

```
struct functor
{
    int operator()(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    double operator()(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
    void operator()(char, char) { return;  }
};

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::make_tuple(1, 2.0, 'a');
    auto t2 = std::make_tuple(2, 4.0, 'b');
    tuple_for_each(functor{}, t1, t2);
    return 0;
}
```

The `functor` object needs to force the use of the `void` path, because evaluating function on the third tuple element returns `void`. But our enable check only looks at the first element. And because the failure happens *after* SFINAE-driven "overload" resolution, SFINAE can't save us here.

But equally, we can't double-unpack the `enable_if_t` expression for the same reason that we couldn't do it when invoking the function: the parameter pack expansion gets confused and tries to iterate both at the same time.

And this is where I come unstuck. I need an indirection morally equivalent to the one used to call the function, but I can't immediately see how to write that indirection such that it actually works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You only need one version of `tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, Tuples&&... ts);`. `void f(); void /* or decltype(auto) */ g(){ return f(); }` is OK.

Comment: Oh, good spot, the perils of incremental alterations. It made more sense when it was where I was hanging the `enable_if_t` checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A holder of types:

```
template<class...> class typelist {};
```

An alias template to compute the result of applying `F` to the `I`-th element of each tuple in `Tuples`:

```
template<class F, std::size_t I, class...Tuples>
using apply_result_type = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::get<I>(std::declval<Tuples>())...));
```

Now to compute a list of result types:

```
template<class F, std::size_t...Is, class... Tuples>
typelist<apply_result_type<F, Is, Tuples...>...> 
        compute_result_types(typelist<F, Tuples...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>);

template<class F, std::size_t Size, class... Tuples>
using result_types = decltype(compute_result_types(typelist<F, Tuples...>(),
                                                   std::make_index_sequence<Size>()));
```

And check that a typelist has no `void` in it:

```
template<class... Ts>
all_true<!std::is_void<Ts>::value...> do_is_none_void(typelist<Ts...>);

template<class TL>
using has_no_void_in_list = decltype(do_is_none_void(TL()));
```

And finally the actual SFINAE (just showing one):

```
template<typename Function, typename... Tuples, std::size_t... Indices,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<!has_no_void_in_list<result_types<Function,
                                                                       sizeof...(Indices),
                                                                       Tuples...>>{}>>
constexpr void tuple_for_each_aux(Function&& f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>, 
                                  Tuples&&... ts)
{
    using swallow = int[];
    static_cast<void>(swallow{ 0, (tuple_for_each_aux<Indices>(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Tuples>(ts)...), void(), 0)... });
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c4d8fbf33df7b07).

Comment: Hm, looks good in g++. Unfortunately it's pushed the limits of what VC++ can do, though I don't immediately see why it's erroring out.