# Variadic templates of Variadic templates class in c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

given Variadic templates data structure as below ( code from [Eli Bendersky's website](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/)):

```
template <class... Ts> struct tuple {};

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct tuple<T, Ts...> : tuple<Ts...> {
  tuple(T t, Ts... ts) : tuple<Ts...>(ts...), tail(t) {}

  T tail;
};
```

we are able to define something like

```
tuple<double, uint64_t, const char*> t1(12.2, 42, "big");
```

Then how to define a template structure that could accept following signature?

```
Foo<tuple<int,double>, tuple<double,int,long> ...,  tuple<std::string>> foo;
```

I think it would be like this:

```
template<tuple<class... Ts>... Tuples>
struct VariadicTuples {};
```

but it cannot compile. is that because the class in the Variadic templates cannot be Variadic templates? If so, How to make this work?

Comment: In your example with `Foo`, you're not passing the template itself but an instanciation thereof. `template <class... Ts> struct Foo;` is enough for this to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply cannot write that, syntactically. What would `Ts` hold in that situation? It would be different for each type in `Tuples` so it wouldn't really be usable.

What you can do instead is take advantage of Columbo's [`bool_pack`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28253503/2069064) trick:

```
template <bool...> struct bool_pack;

template <bool... v>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, v...>, bool_pack<v..., true>>;
```

To simply `static_assert` that all the `Tuples` are, in fact, `tuple`s and then have `VariadicTuples` be a simple variadic class template:

```
template <typename > struct is_a_tuple : std::false_type { };
template <typename... T> struct is_a_tuple<tuple<T...>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename... Tuples>
struct VariadicTuples {
    static_assert(all_true<is_a_tuple<Tuples>::value...>::value, "!");
};
```