# Type-restricted variadic template functions

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I can write the following to define a function taking any number of arguments:

```
template <typename... Arguments>
void f(Arguments... sums) {
    // Do something.
}
```

and then call it like

```
f(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

But how do I restrict all arguments to e.g. int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Employing `all_true` from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28253503/678093) you could use the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool...> struct bool_pack;

template <bool... v>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, v...>, bool_pack<v..., true>>;

template<typename... Args,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<all_true<std::is_same<int, Args>{}...>{}>>
void f(Args... sums)
{
    // Do something.
}

int main()
{
    f(1, 2, 3, 4);
    f(1.1, 2, 3, 4); // compile error
}
```

[<kbd>live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0814e69e4f2ca446)

Comment: Excellent! This works in Clang 3.6, but not in VS 2015, unfortunately.

Comment: @Petter : For VC++ 2015, use `enable_if_t` on the return type instead of in the template parameter list and change `std::is_same<>{}` to `std::is_same<>::value`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::initializer_list<int>` argument for your function. But unfortunately in this case need to specify extra curly braces around arguments.

```
f({1, 2, 3, 4});
```

Comment: That is true, but I’d like to avoid that, if possible.