# C++11: how to accept user-supplied functions elegantly?

Tags: function, c++11, lambda, variadic-functions, arity

I am trying to offer users of my library to supply their own calculation functions, that need to maintain the rules:

- returns a `float` value
- may require 0 to 7 `float` arguments
- no exceptions possible

I got a solution - see below - but it is bulky and ugly. I would bet there is a more elegant way to solve it with templates and type_traits, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

```
// Copyright 2022 bla 
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <math.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class D {
public:
  using Dlambda0 = std::function<float()>;
  using Dlambda1 = std::function<float(float)>;
  using Dlambda2 = std::function<float(float, float)>;
  using Dlambda3 = std::function<float(float, float, float)>;
  using Dlambda4 = std::function<float(float, float, float, float)>;
  using Dlambda5 = std::function<float(float, float, float, float, float)>;
  using Dlambda6 = std::function<float(float, float, float, float, float, float)>;
  using Dlambda7 = std::function<float(float, float, float, float, float, float, float)>;

  D(const char *name, Dlambda0 dFn) : n(name), fn0 {std::move(dFn)} { cout << name << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; arity = 0; }
  D(const char *name, Dlambda1 dFn) : n(name), fn1 {std::move(dFn)} { cout << name << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; arity = 1; }
  D(const char *name, Dlambda2 dFn) : n(name), fn2 {std::move(dFn)} { cout << name << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; arity = 2; }
  D(const char *name, Dlambda3 dFn) : n(name), fn3 {std::move(dFn)} { cout << name << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; arity = 3; }
  D(const char *name, Dlambda4 dFn) : n(name), fn4 {std::move(dFn)} { cout << name << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; arity = 4; }
  D(const char *name, Dlambda5 dFn) : n(name), fn5 {std::move(dFn)} { cout << name << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; arity = 5; }
  D(const char *name, Dlambda6 dFn) : n(name), fn6 {std::move(dFn)} { cout << name << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; arity = 6; }
  D(const char *name, Dlambda7 dFn) : n(name), fn7 {std::move(dFn)} { cout << name << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; arity = 7; }

  float operator() () { return callForArity(0, nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf("")); }
  float operator() (float a) { return callForArity(1, a, nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf("")); }
  float operator() (float a, float b) { return callForArity(2, a, b, nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf("")); }
  float operator() (float a, float b, float c) { return callForArity(3, a, b, c, nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf("")); }
  float operator() (float a, float b, float c, float d) { return callForArity(4, a, b, c, d, nanf(""), nanf(""), nanf("")); }
  float operator() (float a, float b, float c, float d, float e) { return callForArity(5, a, b, c, d, e, nanf(""), nanf("")); }
  float operator() (float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f) { return callForArity(6, a, b, c, d, e, f, nanf("")); }
  float operator() (float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f, float g) { return callForArity(7, a, b, c, d, e, f, g); }

protected:
  const char *n;
  Dlambda0 fn0;
  Dlambda1 fn1;
  Dlambda2 fn2;
  Dlambda3 fn3;
  Dlambda4 fn4;
  Dlambda5 fn5;
  Dlambda6 fn6;
  Dlambda7 fn7;
  uint8_t arity;

  float callForArity(uint8_t givenArgs, float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f, float g) {
    switch (arity) {
    case 0:
      return fn0();
      break;
    case 1:
      return fn1(a);
      break;
    case 2:
      return fn2(a, b);
      break;
    case 3:
      return fn3(a, b, c);
      break;
    case 4:
      return fn4(a, b, c, d);
      break;
    case 5:
      return fn5(a, b, c, d, e);
      break;
    case 6:
      return fn6(a, b, c, d, e, f);
      break;
    case 7:
      return fn7(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
      break;
    }
    return nanf("");
  }
};

float fix1(float a) {
  return a * a;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  // register some functions
  D function("bla", { []() { return 5; }});
  D function2("blubb", { [](float x, float y) { return x + y; }});
  D function3("Blort", fix1);
  
  cout << function() << endl;                     // Okay
  cout << function2(1.0, 5.5) << endl;            // Okay
  cout << function2(5.5) << endl;                 // Aw!
  cout << function3(5.5) << endl;                 // okay

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the 7 a hard limit for some reason? Because "accept a function with any number of arguments" is far easier to enforce than "stop at 7 specifically".

Comment: Yes, 7 is somewhat arbitrary, but I will need an upper limit. I am writing a small math expression evaluator that will supply the required arguments, and in that context 7 is a lot already.
On top of that, I need to accept user functions with all-``float`` arguments only, so I will need a way to check that as well...

Comment: I was dreaming about using ``sizeof...`` and a ``static_assert`` to check the limit.

Comment: Use `const std::vector<float>&` as an argument?

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev This would completely remove a fixed arity, wouldn't it? And within the user function the user will have to use indexed vector values instead of simple names. Imagine something like ``float sum(float a, float b) { return a + b; }`` as a typical user function.

Comment: Fixed arity - you can still specify it in the constructor (allowed number of parameters). Simpleness - you can easily achieve it by wrapping your functions using lambdas. E.g. `[](const std::vector<float> &v) {return mysimplefun(v[0], v[1], v[2]);}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the exact right idea with `sizeof...` and `static_assert`. We can have `D` take a parameter pack and build the function type from that.

```
template <typename... Ts>
class D {
public:
  using function_type = std::function<float(Ts...)>;
  ...
};
```

Simply enough. Now the assertions. These just go in the class body. It sounds like you mostly already figured out the `sizeof...` part.

```
static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) <= 7, "Too many arguments");
```

Now, for the `float`, it sounds like you want all of the `Ts` to be *literally* `float` (i.e. [`is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)). If "is convertible to `float`" is strong enough for your use case, you might consider replacing `is_same` with [`is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) in these examples. Regardless, you tagged C++11, but if we have C++17, we can write this assertion very easily with [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

```
static_assert((std::is_same<Ts, float>::value && ...), "All args must be floats");
```

If you don't have C++17, we can use [@Columbo's excellent `all_true` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253399/check-traits-for-all-variadic-template-arguments/28253503#28253503).

```
template <bool...>
struct bool_pack;

template <bool... v>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, v...>, bool_pack<v..., true>>;

static_assert(all_true<std::is_same<Ts, float>::value...>::value, "All args must be floats");
```

Now we can construct functions by specifying the number of floats they take

```
D<> function("bla", []() { return 5; });
D<float, float> function2("blubb", [](float x, float y) { return x + y; });
D<float> function3("Blort", fix1);
```

and we can call them

```
std::cout << function() << std::endl;
std::cout << function2(1.0, 5.5) << std::endl;
std::cout << function3(5.5) << std::endl;
```

If we try `function2(5.5)`, we get.... not a bad error message, by C++ template standards

```
so_vv.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
so_vv.cpp:47:29: error: no match for call to ‘(D<float, float>) (double)’
   47 |   std::cout << function2(5.5) << std::endl;               // Aw!
      |                             ^
so_vv.cpp:30:9: note: candidate: ‘float D<Ts>::operator()(Ts ...) [with Ts = {float, float}]’
   30 |   float operator()(Ts... args) {
      |         ^~~~~~~~
so_vv.cpp:30:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

And we can fail our other assertions.

```
D<int> not_allowed("foobar", [](int x) { return 10; });
D<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float> not_allowed2("foobar", [](...) { return 10; });
```

These will fail our `static_assert` calls at compile time.

If you don't like the explicit `D<float, float, float>` template arguments, you can definitely get it down to `D<3>` with some clever use of [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). As for whether or not you can get C++ to completely infer the argument count, I'm not sure. I didn't have good luck getting type inference to go that far, but you might have better luck.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZNNj9owEIbv@RVTKqFQsrCwQpVIiLQV9164VRUyxiBrHTuKHRa64q@XzsQEki5LVQ4Qe@Z93vkIPM8ftpyfTsFnqbkq1wISaawrBMvSxl3ppJLu0LzalJo7aTRTzVuUSr1Ng8CJLFfM4dXKGDUYDNIAYyV3QOdlzvhLfCMLdmlQWkQAU2qJAgEzsG49nUq7tCwTyUWeUDSCHbGjKzWhiwgomKYtC3fIhUYE2SxsGnDFrIU5vAV5uVKSTwMA7133tiRJXUB9mWyUYS5cWOT0yCEv5A4NSG4dc5IvkSsKF1r5S5gNpmFyD5IZfI2gszAGMqYPwIptmQntbKcXv5PW3Set3hc2gso9nU53TJXUSv2I6GeliGohKy3OWfjcM384bDuE98nQ7QI1eB9b1Y0Yv3ag6ZJXe371Kb7MGVPmITcacQ15t9JH4AMtRvdy7KEWYFqlhvSFFdax8JIEb0cyqQoFk4uCOVOEPb@0qhlMqUiFcGWhrwiKUd/UBjKO2KOnbOR@FPpH5sVnKYMvwOIAk6V2uFqpQx@fJ@mV21kp1ongx08K1tJJDMfKae5fqnoHF9mYdOVq5ZXefX/OgkODtIc@HP6iXTFPYeebMoVDDLXRWBw3pYMkudbZo1MVEnqtYrj1GQ7h@ws7fMQYh6PBYwSTweQO7MqgF/Mm5T7AM55fP31UxtO/ARXCUBlVHfMEN5iCNm6J/z/zKtZhZ2PMihV@/rTffWPoo8d64qRtbvC/f1qu47YtvY7vTY/B6fSbbxTb2tMDdjjj/f5o9Ac)

Comment: Brilliant! You explained it in such plain words I understood it right away! Thanks a lot, I will give that a try. :+1:

Comment: May I ask for your assistance one more time? I now am trying to put the defined functions in a vector to later access them by index (or rather, pointers to the ``D`` instances). I again cannot find the right way to call the functions I am afraid:

Comment: I created a class Dbase that is inherited by all D template classes and tried to have a ``vector<Dbase *>`` for that.
BTW: How can I put the revised code here again?

Comment: Never mind, found a way: 
``float r =  (*reinterpret_cast<D0>(flist[0]))();
  cout << "R=" << r << endl;`` with ``using D0 = D<> *;``